# Shortcut for alpha channel in render window?

Tags: interface

Is there an existing shortcut to display the alpha channel in the render window, or a way to set one up? 'a' is working but only if I manually expand the "Display Channels" menu with the mouse first.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can, at least not in the popup version.  Blender creates that window on the fly, so there's no permanent internal data that you could hook a shortcut to.